# using function in mysql query statment

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im facing issue while using function in mysql query, im not sure if its wrong to use function in this way , if its wrong how can i do it,
i want to pass the news date column to function which will convert it to different language

this is my query

```
$this->db->query('SELECT *, arabicDate(NewsCreatedAt) AS NewsDate  FROM pressreleases');
return $query->result();
```

//this function is to convert date from english to arabic language

```
 public function arabicDate($date)
 {
     //some code
     return $date;
 }
```

its show error arabicDate does not exist

Comment: You can't use PHP functions in SQL quries

Comment: You *could* possibly replicate the functionality within a MySQL User-Defined Function though: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-functions.html - might be overkill when you could just convert the date after selecting it mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use PHP functions in MySQL code.  As far as the database is concerned, just select the values you need:

```
'SELECT *, NewsCreatedAt AS NewsDate FROM pressreleases'
```

Then *in your PHP code* you can use your *PHP function* when displaying or in some way using that value:

```
echo 'The Arabic date is: ' . arabicDate($someQueryResultObj->NewsDate);
```

Comment: thank you Daved .. i dont want to echo the date.. i want to return $query->result() and the new converted date will be included in it .. because im using the result in the API

Comment: @ahmdabos: Without knowing what you mean by "the API", the general point remains the same.  Select the data from the database, then transform it in PHP code when you use it.  The `echo` is just an example of one way to use the value.  However *you* use it, that's where you'd transform it in PHP code.  You could also transform it directly on the query result object immediately after receiving that query result.